# Fancybox2: Amending call for multiple galleries

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I am generating an HTML page containing multiple galleries from information held in a MySQL database and I need to amend the Fancybox2 call as follows

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[rel=gall24],a[rel=gall30], etc, etc etc").fancybox({ ... });
});
```

How do I add the element references to the call? That is, I need to add a variable number of `a[rel=XXX]`, to the call.

Do I create a variable with the values and reference that in the call? If so I am not sure of the syntax and would appreciate an example.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You may use a single script like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.fancybox").fancybox();
});
```

Then, when you create your galleries just add a different `rel` attribute for each gallery but the same `class="fancybox"`, e.g.:

```
<!--gallery 01 -->
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" rel="gallery01">image 01</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/02.jpg" rel="gallery01">image 02</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/03.jpg" rel="gallery01">image 03</a>

<!--gallery 02 -->
<a class="fancybox" href="images/04.jpg" rel="gallery02">image 04</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/05.jpg" rel="gallery02">image 05</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="images/06.jpg" rel="gallery02">image 06</a>
```

When you click on any image (image 01 for instance) it will show in the (Fancybox) gallery only those elements with the same `rel` attribute (image 02 and 03 as in the example above + image 01 of course)

With fancybox v2.x you don't need to use `jQuery live()` as suggested by @sczizzo since fancybox v2.x already supports both existing and dynamically added elements

**One last note**: don't use ID's for more than a single element. ID's should be unique and you shouldn't use the same ID twice or more times in the same html document.
Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#support FAQ's No.6 for more

Comment: Many thanks.  Works a treat. I did not realise, that having specified a class, Fancybox2, would find all the matching images for that particular REL reference.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just call `fancybox()` multiple times? You can save the options you pass in and use them later.

On the other hand, you might also use a class instead of the `a[rel=XYZ]` selectors, which is what I would do:

```js
$('a.gallery').fancybox({ ... });
```

If the content is being loaded in dynamically (e.g. via Ajax), you might do something similar using jQuery's `live()`.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I just want to have one call to fancybox2, with the different gallery IDs on document ready. The options are the same for all galleries. I could use ID, but is there any advantage over REL.  I don't think I could use Class as that implies same. Jquery live() is a bit beyond my knowledge level at the moment. The gallery details are returned to my script from PHP and then I create the thumbnails within a DIV for each Gallery.