# Fancybox navigation arrows not showing up

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am a newbie to jquery. All animations like transitions and speed is working fine. However, 'showNavArrows' and 'cyclic' isn't working.
Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#single_image").fancybox({
        'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
        'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
        'speedIn'   :   600, 
        'speedOut'  :   200, 
        'overlayShow'   :   false,
        'cyclic'    :   true,
        'showNavArrows' :   true
    })
});
```

Here's the available options:
http://fancybox.net/api

Comment: Open your site in Firefox, press CTRL+SHIFT+K, reload the site and run the fancybox thingie. Does it report any JavaScript errors?

Comment: I checked no error displayed on firefox and also not working on chrome as well!!

Comment: Do you have the png sprite in the correct folder?

Comment: Yes, all the icons are in the same folder named 'fancybox'. However, I had one more question after seeing an example do I need to create groups. Like here's the example source code: $("a[rel=example_group]").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  : 'none',
    'transitionOut'  : 'none',
    'titlePosition'  : 'over',
    'titleFormat'  : function(title, currentArray, currentIndex, currentOpts) {
     return '<span id="fancybox-title-over">Image ' + (currentIndex + 1) + ' / ' + currentArray.length + (title.length ? ' &nbsp; ' + title : '') + '</span>';
    }
   });

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Cyclic and navigation arrows only will show up if you have a group of elements in a gallery, which means that the elements of the gallery should have the same `rel` attribute [check this post for examples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8672233/1055987)

As @Pasha Maigutyak pointed out [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47590519/248616),
if using fancybox v3+, it requires to set `data-fancybox="some group/gallery name"` to see the navbar

Answer (score 8):

If you use fancybox3 try `data-fancybox="images"` instead of `rel="images"`